# How to add a command to launch a new tab in the browser with this code in JavaScript? (etc.) (with Terminal)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a noob. I have a code to simulate a terminal.  This is it: https://codepen.io/isdampe/pen/YpgOYr.

Command:

```
 var coreCmds = {
    "clear": clear
  };
```

Answer (clear the screen):

```
function clear(argv, argc) {
    termBuffer = "";
    return "";
  }
```

As mentioned in the title, how to add a command to launch a new tab in the browser (to google.com for example, or anywhere else)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **window.open()**;

---

The open() method opens a new browser window, or a new tab, depending on your browser settings and the parameter values.

*Here's an example:*

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

### **Structure:**

---

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
```

Since you want to open a new tab in browser, you should put `_blank` in name. However, this is the default.

### What would your code look like?

---

This is a rough outline, replace variable names and arguments as you like

```
 var var_name = {
    "new window": new_window
  };

function new_window(arguments) {
    termBuffer = "";
    return window.open(arguments);
  }
```

I hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.open` method with an input URL.

```js
window.open('https://google.com')
```

This would open a tab to `https://google.com`.